# Show that $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ with This Initial Data Has No Analytic Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The initial data is $u(x, 0) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$.

Rewritten in series form:
$$u(x, 0) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-x^2)^k = 1 - x^2 + x^4 \ldots$$
I am aware that the solution is a Fourier series, so the associated series is different.  However, since the instructor did not cover solving heat equations yet, so I think that he is referring to something else.  What else is wrong?

Comment: The solution of $u_t = u_{xx}$ on the domain $(t,x)\in (0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ with initial condition $u(0,x) = f(x)$ [can be written](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions) $$u(t,x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}f(y)\,{\rm d}y$$ What do you mean by "no analytical solution" here?